# How to enforce Chrome to play html5 video from cache

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have some mp4 files and I would like to play them on page one by one using javascript.

```
var videoSource = new Array(
    cdn + "/video/1.mp4",
    cdn + "/video/2.mp4",    
    cdn + "/video/3.mp4",
    cdn + "/video/4.mp4"
);
var videoCount = videoSource.length;
var i = 0;
video = document.getElementById("video-main");
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("video-player");
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (i == videoCount) i = 0;
    var nextVideo = videoSource[i++];
    videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", nextVideo);
    video.load();
    video.play();
});
```

The playlist runs as expected but after I play the videos for many times, most videos still try to connect to CDN with `HTTP 206` and it cost traffic.

I expect to get `HTTP 304` for all played videos and chrome can get them from local cache.

I host my videos on AWS S3 and serve it by CloudFront.
The settings I have done:

1. Setup video metadata on S3

   - Cache-Control: max-age=1296000
   - Expires: Mon, 27 Mar 2038 13:33:37 GMT
2. When execute chrome, add `–disk-cache-size=1073741824`

Comment: BTW, I the html5 tag I used is <video id="video-main" autoplay preload="none"> .... </video>

Comment: How big are those videos (file size)? Perhaps they don’t fit into cache completely. And status code 206 means that the server answered with partial content, i.e. most likely the client requested only a specific part of the resource (a _byte range_) – that is nothing bad per se, but rather something you want; because otherwise f.e. jumping to different parts of the video would not even work before it is fully loaded (at least up to that part.)

Comment: The four videos are small (<100mb). I find the issue should be on video.load();.  When I manually switch the four videos on html5 video tag, chrome show me HTTP 304 and it reads video from local cache.